# in java, how to delete one folder/dir by non recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, filesystems

How can I delete one folder/directory by a non-recursive algorithm in Java? I want to use a non-recursive algorithm in order to avoid `StackOverflowErrors` when a folder has a very deep path.

Could someone please offer some advise in this area.

Comment: Must have been pretty deep!

Comment: I agree with @EJP... Either that or your stack size is crazy small!

Comment: Yep, unless you've got a really bad directory vine, there should be no problem using recursion.  But of course recursion can always be replaced with a loop and a data stack, if you insist.

Comment: Why would you need a recursion to delete one specific directory?

Comment: @Attila Because you can't delete non-empty directories. To @jiafu, maybe you've got a symlink in this directory tree which points to one of its ancestors?, e.g. `foo/bar/baz` is a symlink to `foo`? If that's the case and you follow the symlinks (which I believe will happen by default), you'll get an infinite loop -- which in recursion means a stack overflow.

Comment: Use one loop to find all directories, then start from there.

Comment: frankly speacking, I know we can't have so much level for one folder, I want to know how to use the non recursive algorithm to instead the common solutions.

Comment: could someone give code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In crappy pseudo-code, as I don't have a Java compiler handy to test this:

```
queue = [ rootDir ]
stack = []

while ( !queue.isEmpty() ) {
    currentDir = queue.take()
    stack.push( currentDir )
    files = currentDir.list()
    for ( f : files ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            queue.add( f )
        } else {
            f.delete()
        }
    }
}

while ( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
    f = stack.pop()
    f.delete()
}
```

Basically this code should scan a directory, deleting files or queueing subdirectories for further scanning. It places scanned directories in a stack, so that the second `while` loop deletes them in the correct order (deepest first).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general way to delete a file/folder :

```
/**deletes a file/folder recursively, and returns true iff succeeded */
public static boolean deleteQuietly(File file) {
    if (file == null || !file.exists())
        return true;
    if (!file.isDirectory())
        return file.delete();
    LinkedList<File> dirs = new LinkedList<>();
    dirs.add(0, file);
    boolean succeededDeletion = true;
    while (!dirs.isEmpty()) {
        file = dirs.remove(0);
        File[] children = file.listFiles();
        if (children == null || children.length == 0)
            succeededDeletion &= file.delete();
        else {
            dirs.add(0, file);
            for (File child : children)
                if (child.isDirectory())
                    dirs.add(0, child);
                else
                    succeededDeletion &= child.delete();
        }
    }
    return succeededDeletion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is just a starting point for you to improve on.

The critical part is to find out what's the directories to delete.

This piece of psuedo code should help you to find out all directories under certain directory:

```
Set<File> allDirectories = new Set<File>();
allDirectories.add(yourStartingDirectory);


while (hasMoreToRead) { 
  hasMoreToRead = false;
  for (File f : allDirectories) {
    if (f.isDirectory() && !allDirectories.contains(f)) {
      allDirectories.add(f);
      hasMoreToRead = true;
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a starting point, but you should be able to finish the rest:  Avoid revisiting directories in `allDirectories` that has been processed in previous iterations; Performing delete base on `allDirectories`; Make the delete more efficient by deleting in  "correct" order; etc

Answer (score 1):

```
// Deletes all files and subdirectories under dir.
// Returns true if all deletions were successful.
// If a deletion fails, the method stops attempting to delete and returns false.
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: this is classic RECURSIVE algorithm, topic search algorithm without recursive

Answer (score 1):

To remove recursion, you replace the call stack with an explicit stack to hold the items you still need to process. In your case, you keep track of all the parent folders you need to delete after you are done with the current one. Here's an example using a LinkedList as a stack:

```
public static void rmdir(File dir) {
    LinkedList<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
    dirs.push(dir);

    while (dirs.peek() != null) {
        dir = dirs.pop();
        File[] contents = dir.listFiles();

        if (contents.length == 0) {
            dir.delete();
        } else {
            dirs.push(dir);

            for(File content : contents) {
                if (content.isDirectory()) {
                    dirs.push(content);
                } else {
                    content.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting recursion model - you can also add a test on delete() action.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to delete a directory without recursing into the directories within it. In this case, you can implement the deletion using a pretty simple loop...

```
File directory = new File("c:\\directory_path")
if (!directory.exists()){
    return;
}

File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    if (files[i].isFile()){
        boolean deleted = files[i].delete();
        if (!deleted){
            System.out.println("Problem deleting file " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

This will list all the `Files` of the directory in an array, and then loop through them. If the file is a `normal file`, it will be deleted. Non-normal files, such as directories, will be skipped.

Of course, there are other similar alternatives, such as adding a `FileFilter` to the `listFiles()` method so that the array is only populated by normal files, but its effectively pretty similar.

If you want to delete the directory tree, you will have to use some kind of recursion. You could approach it differently though, which might not cause you so many problems, such as building an `ArrayList` of directories, and then iterating through the `ArrayList` deleting them one at a time. This would help to reduce the recursion.

Comment: That won't delete a directory tree.

Comment: I interpreted the users question as only wanting to delete 1 directory/folder, and not recurse into the directories within it.

Comment: @WATTOStudios That doesn't make sense, you wouldn't need recursion or get a StackOverflowError from deleting files in one directory.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee if the user does `new File("C:\\directory").delete();`, it will internally recurse through the directory removing the files within it, will it not? If the user just wants to delete the *contents* of the directory, they need to list the files in it and delete them, rather than deleting the higher-level directory. It really depends on what the user is asking, which isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to delete one file tree not only file with first level

Comment: @jiafu Okay, see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final void delete(File file) throws IOException
{
    if (!file.exists())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File does not exist: " + file);

    if (file.isFile())
    {
        simpleDelete(file);
        return;
    }

    Deque<File> dirsQueue = new ArrayDeque<File>();
    dirsQueue.push(file);

    for (File dir; (dir = dirsQueue.peekLast()) != null;)
    {
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();

        if (children == null)
            throw new IOException("Unable to read directory: " + dir);

        if (children.length == 0)
        {
            simpleDelete(dir);
            dirsQueue.removeLast();
            continue;
        }

        for (File child : children)
        {
            if (child.isDirectory())
                dirsQueue.addLast(child);
            else
                simpleDelete(child);
        }
    }
}

private static final void simpleDelete(File file) throws IOException
{
    if (!file.delete())
        throw new IOException("Unable to delete " + (file.isDirectory() ? "directory" : "file") + ": " + file);
}
```